# Custom shortcuts for selecting brushes?

Tags: shortcut, sculpting

i went to user preferences, 3d view, sculpt, then i scrolled down a clicked on add new, but how can i add a bush short cut? the existing bush short cuts look different than the one that i added. Any suggestions?

thank you, here was my attempt.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a keyboard with a number pad. Do you have another work around.

Comment: I don't mean using numpad for that, rather than numbers just over the main keyboard (where letters are). Still, if it really doesn't work for you, you can [create a new shortcut](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/adding-a-custom-shortcut-for-sculpt-mode) or edit exhisting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, pressing <kbd>C</kbd> in Sculpt Mode will select the Clay brush.

Similarly, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will select the Crease brush.

You can simply change either of these shortcuts to the Clay Strips brush instead. Or you could add a new shortcut of your own using the same syntax.

In the screen shot below, notice how I've changed the function of the second shortcut to trigger the Clay Strips brush instead of the Crease brush.

[image: Customizing the brush selection shortcuts]

Let's say you want to add your own instead of modifying the existing shortcuts. It's as easy as clicking "Add New", pasting in `paint.brush_select`, setting the Paint Mode to Sculpt, then selecting which Sculpt Tool you want. And of course specify the key, and the modifier key(s) if any.